# filter columns script google sheets

Tags: javascript, filter, google-sheets

Below is the script I am using to hide sheets and filter visible area.  I am attempting to filter the column that contains the current date and only show cell rows with text in that column. The filter should only be active between 9 and 10 am.  Any thoughts?

```
function onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // or .getSheets()[0]; to apply to the first sheet.
var dates = sheet.getRange(1, 4, 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - 1).getValues()[0];
var today = Date.now()
var n = d.getHours();

if (n >= 9 && n <= 10){
   filterSettings.range = {
    sheetId: ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
  };

  filterSettings.criteria = {};
  var columnIndex = "column with today's date";
  filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
    'not null' : condition_value
  };
 } else { 
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var ssId = ss.getId();

     var dataSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
     var lastColumn = dataSheet.getLastColumn();
     var sheetId = dataSheet.getSheetId();

     var filterSettings = {
       "range": {
         "sheetId": sheetId,
         "startRowIndex": 0,
         "endRowIndex": lastRow,
         "startColumnIndex": 0,
         "endColumnIndex": lastColumn
       }
     };
 var requests = [{
   "setBasicFilter": {
     "filter": filterSettings
 }
}];
 Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, ssId);
}
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, your main question (and please stick to a single question at a time) is that you want to use date criteria in filters or filter views? If so, make sure this is clear in the question with an [edit], and make sure you do a little research here and elsewhere to see if this is answered already.

Comment: I have revised my question.  Thanks for the clarification.  I have looked at some posts but nothing that refers to columns and filtering only the column with a specific criteria.  I'll keep checking. Thanks